# How could I inject spring-data repository on SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom Authentication Success Handler like this:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     ....
  }
}
```

How could I inject my Spring-Data repository here? I try do with different ways but with no success. =/

Comment: " I try do with different ways but with no sucess" => Show your tries, it can be useful.

Comment: +1 to what Getz said. From all that is visible so far and assuming a working spring setup a simply autowiring the DataSource (are you using one?) in, should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, someone could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new bean class to hold the static references and method to get the repository reference to use. Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to populate the static reference.

```
@Service
public class RepositoryBeans {
  private static RepositoryBeans instance;

  @Autowired
  private Repository repository;

  public static Repository getRepository() {
    return instance.repository;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    instance = this;
  }
}
```